# Get list of applications in OKTA using Jquery

Tags: okta, okta-api

Hi is there a way to get users applications list in OKTA via jquery? Right now we are using Okta Iframe on our page, problem is that the okta content cannot be changed.

Answer (score 0):

The operation that [lists users assigned to an application](https://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/apps#list-users-assigned-to-application) is part of the [Apps API](https://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/apps), which requires an API token. For security reasons, you can't call it from jQuery code.

If you have a backend or API component to your application, you can use that to call this API securely and then pass the results to your frontend.